# Narratives in Haitian (or other) Vodou?

Tags: reference-request

While there are plenty of modern and literary references to the Loas, I can't seem to find any narratives of the Loas themselves. Are there any narratives available or are the Loas best defined by their personalities and spheres of influence?

Comment: This is a great question.  Welcome to Mythology!